# where are the project assets stored in wp7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I wanted to access a few of my assets ... in particular, my app comes with a bunch of text files and mp3 files.

They are not downloaded from the net later, but come with the app itself. so I was wondering how the isolated storage comes into the picture if at all ?

all I want to do is read the text file / play the mp3 file. And these files come with the app itself.
I know the location of the files relative to the project folder. some thing like  :

project/textFiles/textFile1.txt

...

project/mp3Files/mp3File1.txt

...

how do I access these files ? the general filestream /  streamreader ....doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: The build process will output a your_project.xap file.  This is just a zip-compressed file.  Rename it to your_project.zip and you can open it up and see the internal structure.  Also, you may need to specify `UriKind.Relative` when creating the Uri you want to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your .txt files as "Content" and then use code like the following:

```
Uri uriMyFile = new Uri("myfilename.txt",UriKind.relative);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader((Application.GetResourcesStream(uriMyFile)).Stream);
```

the application class provides access to the appropriate stream.

Comment: That's `GetResourceStream`, only one resource.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a `Resources` folder under your project's root directory. Make sure that the `Build Action` (in the Properties window) for all files under this folder that you want to access is set to `Content` and the `Copy to Output Directory` option is set to `Copy if Newer` or `Copy Always`.

I've never tried to read a text file, but I am loading an XML file that is packaged with my app as follows:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load( "Resources/MyData.xml" );
```

I think I remember having problems if I used a leading `/` in the path.

Answer (score -1):

they get packaged up into the .xap file which gets deployed